# ngx-charts found version 4, expected 3,

Tags: angular, package.json, ngx-charts

I just installed ngx-charts when i add it in app-module i get this error.

> ERROR in Error: Metadata version mismatch for module E:/Licenta/licenta/node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-charts/release/index.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3, resolving symbol AppModule in E:/Licenta/licenta/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in E:/Licen
>   ta/licenta/src/app/app.module.ts

this is my package.json dependencies and devDependencies verions

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/schematics": "0.0.40",
"@angular/animations": "^4.4.6",
"@angular/cdk": "^5.0.4",
"@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/material": "^5.0.4",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
"@ngui/auto-complete": "^0.16.0",
"@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^7.0.1",
"angular-font-awesome": "^2.3.7",
"angular-slide-menu": "^0.5.0",
"angular2-fontawesome": "^0.9.3",
"bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"d3": "^4.12.2",
"font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
"ionicons-npm": "^2.0.1",
"ng-sidebar": "^6.0.4",
"ng2-auto-complete": "^0.12.0",
"ng2-charts": "^1.6.0",
"ng2-input-autocomplete": "0.0.11",
"ngx-bootstrap": "^1.9.1",
"primeng": "^4.2.2",
"rxjs": "^5.4.1",
"zone.js": "^0.8.14"}


"devDependencies": {
"@angular/cli": "^1.6.3",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/language-service": "^4.0.0",
"@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
"@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
"@types/node": "~6.0.60",
"codelyzer": "~3.0.1",
"jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
"karma": "~1.7.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
"karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
"karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
"protractor": "~5.1.2",
"ts-node": "~3.0.4",
"tslint": "~5.3.2",
"typescript": "2.4.2"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ngx-charts v7.0.0 supports Angular 5 only. 
The error you got was because you are using "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0" which complains about a version mismatch in the metadata when using the Angular 5 compiled ngx-charts version 7.0.0.

You should upgrade to Angular 5.

You can use NCU to update all dependencies :

```
npm install -g npm-check-updates

ncu -u

npm install
```